# Casting void pointer to struct pointer does not return correct pointers inside structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct, casting

I have a function that allows me to set some `void *user_data` which I am using to store a pointer to a `struct job_data` defined as:

```
struct job_data {
  int *i
  struct *j;
}
```

It does this by allowing me to pass my pointer to the **user_data** setting function through the call, so if I've got `struct job_data job_info`, I would set it via `set_user_data(&job_info)` where *set_user_data* receives a `void *` as a parameter.

However, when I get my pointer back later and cast it via `struct job_data *job=user_data`, the pointers inside (**job.i** and **job.j**) are set to different pointers than in the original **job_data** structure that I had cast to `void *`. Why is that? What should I do differently to recapture my original **i** and **j** pointers?

Comment: Please post a simplified version of your function, as well as how you call it.

Comment: and also specify how and where is original `job_info` declared,

Comment: Most likely: The scope that allocated `struct job_data job_info` on the stack no longer exists when you retrieve your pointer.

Comment: @SergeyL.: I though about it but that wouldn't change the pointer, this would just invalidate dereference of fields.

Comment: @Jack Exactly! The contents of the struct will have been overwritten by then. That is why he is observing different values for `i` and `j` then were intended.

Comment: @SergeyL. - you are right. that was the problem. Thanks. If you want to write that into an official answer, I will make sure you get credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the scope that allocated `struct job_data job_info` on the stack no longer exists when you retrieve your pointer.

If the scope has ended by the time you retrieve your pointer then the contents will most likely have been overwritten by then.

You can fix this by either making sure the scope is valid as long as the pointer has to be accessed or to allocate the struct on the heap (`malloc` and family).